# How do I check if a String contains the same letter more than once?

Tags: java, string

I'm a bit confused in how I would check if a String contains the same letter more than once.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

words.add("zebra");
words.add("buzzer");
words.add("zappaz");
```

Let's say I only want to print out any words which contain more than one "z", therefore only "buzzer" and "zappaz" would get printed. How would I do this?

Comment: Are you interested in doubled z or any doubled letter ?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I'm only interested in a "z" occurring more than once anywhere in the string, not a double letter. I have a way of doing it but it is really long and messy which iterates through the chars of the letters :/ but I thought there must be a better way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A smart solution could be, removing the character you want to search and compare the length of the resulting string with the complete string.

```
ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

words.add("zebra");
words.add("buzzer");
words.add("zappaz");

for (String word : words) {
  // calculate the length difference
  if (word.length() - word.replace("z", "").length() > 1) {
    System.out.println(word);
  }
}
```

will print:

```
buzzer
zappaz
```

Not very efficient, but it works and is pretty simple.

Comment: This is a super-smart approach.

Answer (score 8):

To test if a string contains two z, you can do this :

```
 boolean ok = word.matches(".*z.*z.*")
```

Comment: Note it fails for multiline string

Comment: @amit given we're speaking of "words", I guess that's not a problem here

Comment: Just a comment, and a "note", not downvoting or anything.

Comment: @amit No worry. For interested readers, for the sake of completion, note that you could build a pattern with the flag `Pattern.DOTALL` to match also multi lines "words".

Answer (score 6):

`indexOf` returns the... index of... a character in a string. It also takes an optional argument specifying where to search. If there is no match, it returns `-1`. So just use it twice:

```
s.indexOf(letter, s.indexOf(letter) + 1) > -1
```

[It works!](http://ideone.com/yDG2TH)

(For efficiency's sake, though, may as well [check the first result](http://ideone.com/1XFlns).)

Comment: Oh... I want this hat... how did you get it ?

Comment: @dystroy: It's like the Populist badge, except easier. That is all ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String s = "bazzer";
  String news = s.replaceAll("z", "");

    if(news.length() < s.length() -1 ){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

  }
```

Comment: very nice solution :)